# ubuntu16.04 - network interface unexpectedly rename to eth-* from ens-*

Tags: networking, server, virtualization, dhcp, kvm-virtualization

kernel:        4.4.0-101-generic
environment:   openstack+kvm
expected:      network-interfaces are named as ens-*
description:
`After reboot, check the "ip -a", the network interfaces become eth-*`

1. check grub already.
2. /etc/network/interface.d & udev =>
   [udev & interface.d](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQdW8.png)
3. content inside interface.d/50-cloud-init.cfg , nothing particular
   `auto ens0
   iface ens0 inet dhcp
   auto ens1
   iface ens1 inet dhcp`
4. udevadm is missing...(does this matter ?)

Any advise or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What did you check in GRuB?  I know that to disable the predictable naming of the network you need to add `net.ifnames=0` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` line in `/etc/default/grub`.  Then you `sudo update-grub` for the changes to take effect on the next reboot.  Or, remove it if it exists.

Comment: @Terrance 
in the grub file, GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
and this is what I checked.
I want predictable naming rule like ens-*  instead of eth-*.

Comment: You might need to reinstall `udev`, `sudo apt install --reinstall udev` which will reinstall the `udevadm`.  Also, you could try adding `net.ifnames=1` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` line.